# Is fragment shader necessary in Intel HD graphic card?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, intel

I have a question about the fragment shader.
In my case for transform feedback in GL, the vertex shader is used in the program only without any fragment shader, and it work well with NVIDIA (GeForce940M) but not in my Intel HD 5500 (glerror GL_INVALID_OPERATION, 0x0502 at glBeginTransformFeedback). 
Is fragment shader necessary in Intel HD graphic card? or there get something different setup between NVIDIA and Intel HD?

The major part of my simple code to show the problem (ignore the GL init.):

```
.
.
.
GLuint countQuery;
glGenQueries(1, &countQuery);
const std::string init_Vertex_Code =
"#version 330 core  \n"
"\n  "
"layout (location = 0) in vec4 vPos;  \n "
"layout (location = 1) in vec4 vColor;  \n "
"layout (location = 2) in vec4 vNorm;  \n "
"out vec4 vPos0;  \n "
"out vec4 vColor0;  \n "
"out vec4 vNorm0;  \n "
"void main()  \n "
"{  \n     "
"vPos0 = vPos;  \n     "
"vColor0 = vColor;  \n     "
"vColor0.y = 0;  \n     "
"vColor0.z = 1;  \n     "
"vNorm0 = vNorm;  \n "
"}  \n ";

//initProgram
GLenum initProgram;
initProgram = glCreateProgram();
GLhandleARB shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
const char* source = init_Vertex_Code.c_str();
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, NULL);
glCompileShader(shader);
glAttachShader(initProgram, shader);
glLinkProgram(initProgram);

//initBuffer
std::pair<GLuint, GLuint> vbos;
const int bufferSize = 512 * 512 * sizeof(float) * 3;
float * vertices = new float[bufferSize];

glGenBuffers(1, &vbos.first);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos.first);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferSize, &vertices[0], GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

//initFeedback
const bool NVIDIA = false;  //true for NV, false for Intel
glUseProgram(initProgram);
if (NVIDIA){
    const int locInit[3] =
    {
        glGetVaryingLocationNV(initProgram, "vPos0"),
        glGetVaryingLocationNV(initProgram, "vColor0"),
        glGetVaryingLocationNV(initProgram, "vNorm0"),
    };
    glTransformFeedbackVaryingsNV(initProgram, 3, locInit, GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);
}
else{
    const GLchar* feedbackVaryings[] = { "vPos0", "vColor0", "vNorm0" };
    glTransformFeedbackVaryings(initProgram, 3, feedbackVaryings, GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);
}
glGenTransformFeedbacks(1, &vbos.second);

glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, vbos.second);
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, vbos.first);
glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_POINTS);
printf("glBeginTransformFeedback success!\n");
glEndTransformFeedback();
glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, 0);

glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
glUseProgram(0);

glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbos.first);
glDeleteTransformFeedbacks(1, &vbos.second);

glDeleteQueries(1, &countQuery);
```

The zipped file of the full project based on the ogl-samples' gl-410-transform-feadback-object is [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=3dc0dbdb7ba243ef&id=3DC0DBDB7BA243EF!521&authkey=!AEsIw4E_v27ahGg).

Comment: could you share your vertex shader?

Comment: The modified version is updated, thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: if you do not override fragment shader then fixed one is used by the drivers. My bet is Your problem is more likely due to bad drivers from Intel. Their OpenGL implementation is not reliable and got many issues. That is at least my experience. They are OK for older stuff like OpenGL 1.0 ,but when going for GLSL the funny stuff begins ...

Comment: Really? that is a bad news.. The version of my Intel HD is 20.19.15.4463 updated on 25/5/2016...So we can do nothing about that?

Comment: @Robin you can try [nvemulate](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvemulate) from nvidia to emulate any nvidia card and check functionality against that but it will be slow (or temporarily change gfx card) for a test if it works then it confirms my suspicion. Updating intel drivers would make a difference only if they repairs them ... but for example ATI never did such thing until AMD overtake ... so do not hold your hopes up.

Comment: @Robin PS do not forget to add `@nick` to your comments so the user `nick` is notified about your response

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for your friendly reminder! I will try that, but I think that the problem is about the Intel's, not NV, why should I have to test the NV one? Thanks again!

Comment: @Robin to check if it is really the case of Intel bad driver issue or error in your code. nVidia OpenGL drivers are the best from all vendors for years (At least on Windows platform). So if something is not running on them it is most likely bug in code. If it runs and on different card not it is most likely driver issue. But in some cases the nVidia GLSL compilers are more benevolent and allow things other compilers does not. So you should also check the obvious things like missing input/outputs etc